# Using a regular expression with posix syntax to validate an email address

Tags: java, regex

Here is the validation that we have to use for email validation.

Using posix syntax:

```
^[[:graph:]]\\+@[[:graph:]]\\+\\.[[:graph:]]\\+$
```

I have written sample program to validate, but i have failed to give right Email address to fulfill posix syntax regular expression. Could you please any one help me out to correct my below Java example.

### Java Example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegexMatches {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

      String email = "sudheer@gmail.com";
      String pattern ="^[[:graph:]]\\+@[[:graph:]]\\+\\.[[:graph:]]\\+$";
      //String pattern = ".+@.+\\.[a-z]+";// This is Working fine.

      if (!testRegex(email, pattern))
        System.out.println("Validator Exception");
      else
        System.out.println("Success");
    }

     public static boolean testRegex(String value, String regex) {
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
       return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use java syntax. Actually why do you think `"\\+"` is posix? This is escaping the `+` character.

Comment: But still this code is working fine in my system, what's the error your getting?

Comment: I know this is for PHP but you should read it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java you can use:

```
String pattern ="^\\p{Graph}+@\\p{Graph}+\\.\\p{Graph}+$";
```

[**Reference**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

- Use `\\p{Graph}` in Java for `[[:graph:]]` in POSIX
- No need to use double escape quantifier `+`

Comment: What would the equivalent of `[[:graph:]_]` be? i.e. I want to include some other chars in the valid set for a particular token.

Comment: You can use character class in Java [\p{graph}_]